# Changing Pandas Data Frame Layout

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a pandas dataframe that has four fields 'EventDate', 'DataField', 'DataValue'.

'DataField' has three values i.e Oxygen, HeartRate, HeartRateVariability.

[image]

How to change the above format into following format  for analysis?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-to-pivot-a-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

you can try `pivot` :

```
df = df.pivot(*df).fillna('')
```

For more info -> you can check [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) & [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table)

Comment: The use of `*` is really interesting in your answer. Can you please tell me how using the `*` works ?

Comment: If the columns are in order i.e `index/columns/values`. Then we can directly use `*df` and it’ll use the `1st` column as `index`, `2nd` column as `columns` and `3rd` column as `values`

Answer (score 1):

Any time you want to take one attribute in your dataset and group some other attributes by it, you should think about using pandas group_by or pivot_table functionality.

I'm personally a fan of pivot tables, so here is how do it in a pivot table:

```
# Pivot the data
pivot_table = df.pivot_table(
    index=['EventDate'],
    values=['Oxygen', 'HeartRate', 'HeartRateVariability],
    aggfunc={'Oxygen': 'mean', 'HeartRate': 'mean', 'HeartRateVariability': 'mean'}
)
```

By specifying the aggfunc as mean, if there are any EventDates that have multiple records, the resulting pivot table will have the mean of those records listed.

If creating pivot tables is something you do often, you could also checkout some pandas pivot table GUIs. I'm the creator of one called [Mito](https://trymito.io/so). Mito is an extension to Jupyter Lab and it lets you create pivot tables (and other spreadsheet style analyses) in a point and click way. Each time you make an edit in the Mito spreadsheet, it automatically generates the equivalent pandas code for you.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by others, you can use the [pivot_table()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) function, specifically for your case you can try this:

```
pivot_df = df.pivot_table( index = 'EventDate', columns = 'DataField', values = 'DataValue')
```

Comment: Getting following error from using above function                                               
                                                                                                                                  
  ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape

Comment: My apologies, I had tried the code in VS Code, creating a sample DataFrame similar to yours, it had worked. I have edited my answer, and used `pivot_table` instead of `pivot`. I hope it works for you.

Comment: `Pivot_table` allows duplicate index.. 